# Strange ambiguity from Intellisense

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've got the following code (reduced from the actual application, of
course):

```
class Reader
{
    class Proxy
    {
        Reader* myOwner;
    public:
        Proxy( Reader* owner ) : myOwner( owner ) {}
        template <typename T>
        operator T() const
        {
            T tmp;
            myOwner->Read( &tmp );
            return tmp;
        }
    };
public:
    void Read( bool* dest );
    void Read( int* dest );
    void Read( std::string* dest );
    //  ...

    Proxy Read();
};

void
testIt( Reader& r )
{
    std::string s = r.Read();    //  Issue on this line.
}
```

The code compiles fine with both MSC and g++, but Intellisense
highlights the line in question, with an error message to the effect
that more than one user defined conversion from `Reader::Proxy` to
`std::string` applies, and cites all or most of the constructors of
`std::string` which can be called with a single argument.

My real question is: who is right?  My feeling is that because I'm using
the copy initialization form of initialization, the compiler should
first *convert* `Reader::Proxy` to an `std::string`, then copy this.
And that the instantiation `Proxy::operator std::string()` does the conversion
with a single user defined conversion, where as an instantiation like
`Proxy::operator char const*()` would require two: the conversion
operator and the conversion constructor of `std::string`, and would thus
be illegal.  (If I'd used direct initialization, of course, the compiler
would search for all of the conversions which could be used to call
a constructor of `std::string`, and the statement would be ambiguous.)

So is this a bug in Intellisense?  Or is it a case of Intellisense being
closer to the standard, and that my code might stop compiling when we
upgrade, and the newer version follows the standard more closely?

Answer (score 2):

Generally if it works in MSVC and g++ but not Intellisense, it's probably Intellisense that's at fault.

That said, I believe the code you posted is fine.

There is actually an MSVC warning for this (C4928), though it's off by default:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwck4ta9.aspx

You can enable it by using `/w44928` on the command line or in 'extra compile options' in the IDE, or by using `#pragma warning(4:4928)`.

EDIT: Having read the MSDN docs on that warning, it looks like they're suggesting that changing your code to `std::string s(r.Read());` will work without warning. So I guess their wording of the warning isn't quite right (or we're just misreading it?) and they really mean "user-defined conversion and copy initialization being done in one statement". I don't know if that's allowed by the standard or not, sorry.

Comment: I don't think that the code should give a warning.  I _think_ it is legal, even if Intellisense doesn't agree.  (Adding the pragma didn't cause any warnings.)